# How to separate static content on ASP.NET MVC in Apache mod-mono

Tags: mono, monodevelop, mod-mono

I have already a project that built top of the ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and it's working.
I tried to run it on Ubutuntu 10.4 Server on Apache2 and Mod mono.

As you know, when you created a new project on VS.NET it creates a Content folder for holds static content such as css, js, images etc.

Also my project has working with Forms authentication, and i separated some path of my project with below `location` element in web.config.

```
  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But above configuration hasn't worked on Apache.

The question is; how can i pass authentication for static contents on apache - mod mono ?

Thank you